# What is mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript

I am having an immense amount of pain and frustration trying to figure out where I am going wrong.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){ return bindActionCreators({ addThing }, dispatch); };
```

I have no idea what this line does. I don't know where the word dispatch came from, and why there is an action in there.

```
function mapStateToProps(state){ return { things: state.things } }
```

Here, we are passing in the state... I don't how, I don't know where it is coming from, but we are passing it in. Then, `things` is going to be an accessible prop equal to the state that is given. Next, we need to connect this React container to Redux.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addThing })(ThingIndex);
```

I added stuff ehruazshf;suaofhs;ziofp/ So, we throw in the current state of the app, and that function again, and this class. Also, I guess we don't need the `mapDispatchToProps` because the `{addThing}` takes care of it.

Comment: Stackover flow won't let me upload the formatted code, because the format was wrong. So I guess this is muuuuch better.

Comment: Even after properly formatting your post, I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you add more context, especially with where you're running into problems and what you're trying to do?